# Do any routing protocols take link capacity into account?

Tags: routing, ospf

Do there exist any routing protocols which take link capacities and loads into account?

To illustrate the question, suppose there are are multiple paths between a source host A and a destination host B. OSPF will load-balance on a flow-by-flow basis if the paths are of equal cost, but if the links are of non-equal cost, OSPF will only load the lower cost link. More to the point, even in the equal-cost path case, OSPF does not take link loads from other source-destination pairs into account and so may still choose a (badly) sub-optimal assignment of flows to paths. We see that OSPF does not consider link capacity and load but only a static "cost".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do there exist any routing protocols which take link capacities and loads into account?

There are two ways to handle the issues you describe:

- MPLS TE w/ RSVP (complicated)
- EIGRP (easier, but isn't so good out of the box)

***MPLS TE w/ RSVP***:

[MPLS Traffic Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSVP-TE) is not quite a routing protocol, but it adds the capability for OSPF or ISIS to calculate costs based on offered load using IGP extensions that are specific to MPLS-TE ([OSPF Opaque LSAs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3630) or [ISIS Sub-TLVs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5305)).

There are two normal ways of adjusting traffic based on the offered load along  MPLS TE paths:

- One is via what Cisco and Juniper call "automatic bandwidth adjustment" ([Cisco doc](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/mp_te_path_setup/configuration/xe-3s/mp-te-path-setup-xe-3s-book/mp-te-auto-bandwdth.html) / [Juniper doc](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos12.2/topics/usage-guidelines/mpls-configuring-automatic-bandwidth-allocation-for-lsps.html))
- You can also use offline calculations for traffic optimization, and push policies to your MPLS TE nodes.

[MPLS TE w/ RSVP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/multiprotocol-label-switching-mpls/mpls/13731-mpls-te-ospf.html) reserves bandwidth along an entire path, and then each MPLS TE router can be configured to periodically announce updates and even enforce those bandwidth limits per-hop; [Pete Templin's NANOG presentation](https://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog37/presentations/pete-templin.pdf) has a pretty good overview of how this works.   Some people say that Cisco doesn't enforce MPLS TE bandwidth constraints along the path; however, that's actually only part of the story.  If you use [Diffserv-aware TE (DS-TE)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2s/feature/guide/fsdserv3.html), you can enforce bandwidth limits on tunnels (subject to platform / IOS support).

Closing note: your question described link loading problems, which MPLS TE certainly can handle; however, MPLS TE is more of a path-management framework.  MPLS TE is meant to manage multiple paths between routers... with each path being more than one link.

***EIGRP***:

Certainly EIGRP has the capability to adjust IGP costs based on the offered load; however, this capability is disabled by default in EIGRP (for good reason).  The command to enable it is [`metric weights`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_eigrp/configuration/12-4/ire-12-4-book/Configuring_EIGRP.html#GUID-86D573E5-F921-45E2-8062-C2EDEAFC7656), which uses this formula.  The `K2` parameter defaults to 0; when it's non-zero it will take Cisco's interface "load-average" parameter into consideration.

```
EIGRP Metric = 256*((K1*Bw) + (K2*Bw)/(256-Load) + (K3*Delay) + (K5/(Reliability + K4)))
```

However, EIGRP *won't* send updates merely because the load-interval changes, it will only send an update [when there is another topology change](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/message/77820#77820).  The end result is that until there is a topology change, the local router will make decisions based on load; however, other routers won't be aware of those decisions until EIGRP is forced to send updates.  Practically, this EIGRP load-average feature can solve some point problems, but isn't as helpful as MPLS TE in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

EIGRP uses the load indicated by IOS as part of its calculations. EIGRP can also load-balance relatively appropriately on unequal cost paths.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/whitepaper_C11-720525.html